# ubuntu web server without ethernet cable

Tags: webserver

can someone tell me if it is possible to create a web server out of an old PC without using 
an Ethernet cable?i am currently unable to use an Ethernet cable to set up an Ubuntu server and was wondering if it was Evan possible to just use a wireless network adapter.

Comment: Why should it not be possible to use a wireless connection? (Sure, it's probably not the fastest or most stable…) Have you already tried something? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i have already tried to use an adapter but it a peers to only take Ethernet connection.i suspect that it isn't possible given the limited amount of speed of traffic witch may negatively affect the server.

Comment: @internetnoob Ubuntu generally supports wireless connections. It honestly sounds as if you're having another issue.

Comment: Please read http://xyproblem.info/ and update your question with the actual problem you are having.

Comment: i think it is because the version of the os was made for web servers specifically.witch may require an ethernet cable to be used.